# Updaing row in Mysql using PHP that can throw error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have a table user_friend that have something like this schema and data.

```
UID   FID
1      2
3      4
2      4
3      2
```

It shows who is friend with whom, `(UID,FID)` is unique. The problem is sometime I issue statement like

```
update FID in user_friend where FID=4
```

and set it to `2`. But that create 2 identical rows in this table, I want to know that prior to updating that `if FID=4` (4 is just for example) exist or not. So I don't update it.
I can't use

```
select FID from user_friend where fid=4
```

because that will give me `(2 ,4)` as well
I think may be something like group by may help - any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be solved with `UPDATE IGNORE`. Look at this code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf528/1

When you want to `UPDATE` using just `FID` then you should use `UPDATE IGNORE` this way for example:

```
UPDATE IGNORE test SET FID = 2
WHERE FID = 4;
```

This won't produce an error when getting duplicate keys, but will just leave the records be untouched. Now to remove those (you wanted to update them so you don't have records with `FID=4`) you can just call:

```
DELETE FROM test WHERE FID = 4;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: so I have 2 unique rows with this in FID or this will leave it as it is ?

Comment: No, when it tries to update and come across a unique key it will just ignore it and not update this particular row.

Answer (score 1):

Your select query needs to be:

```
SELECT 1 FROM user_friend WHERE uid = ? AND fid = ?
```

You have to know the value of uid and fid. If this query returns a record, you know it exists and you can skip the update.

Alternatively you can do an `INSERT IGNORE` to suppress the error.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO user_friend SET uid = ? AND fid = ?
```

---

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO user_friend SELECT uid, 'xyz' WHERE fid = 'abc'

DELETE FROM user_friend WHERE fid = 'abc'
```

This will 'rename' all records with fid=abc to fid=xyz without giving you errors.

Comment: I dont know UID at the moment.. while I am updating , I just have access to FID.

Comment: Then how will you ever do the `UPDATE`?

Comment: I just do update on FID, update user_friend set FID=abc where FID=xyz

Comment: can Campen the problem is above query creates error full result

Comment: I think I am not successfull in telling you the scenerio, Actually when the rows are inserted in table, there were different UID ,FID, but later on if I update the table I dont want to have same UID , FID combination..

Comment: Try to work with this: http://leo.steamr.com/2011/09/mysql-update-on-duplicate-key-delete-work-around/

Comment: @KeluThatsall exactly this is what I need, but I want that if such thing happend like more than 1 unique row, I want to manupulate that row... and do some other stuff

Comment: @user1765876 You can see my answer to check how it can be done with `UPDATE IGNORE`

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if i get your scenario. 
You can try taking a look at [insert ... on duplicate key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Instead of updating the row, you try to insert it, in case the new row exits, you just edit its contents

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b) VALUES (1,2)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b=2;
```

and then delete previous value

also, you can modify other columns, or even add some logic to the on duplicate key, with if and other functions:

```
INSERT into table
    (a,b)
VALUES
    (1,2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    a = a+1,
    b = 
         IF(VALUES(b) > b, VALUES(b), b);
```

for example to decide which value to keep.

Comment: It won't work cuz he doesn't know what is `a` at the moment of updating.

Comment: this is a code snippet, please, update it to your actual table and column names!

Comment: dude I know that's its not a real code, what I'm trying to tell you is, that the OP wanted to update a table knowing just `b` value, not `a`. So your idea won't work in this case.

Comment: oh! sorry. i misunderstood your comment (many newbies around and that uses to happen, sorry!) Lets see. If you update all the rows where fid=4 and set it to 2, you will get some duplicate rows, but the question is: what do you want exactly to do in this case? keep the old one, and dont update the other? delete one of them?

Comment: well when you try to update that way you will have duplicate keys, therefore an error will popup. You can look at my answer to see how the problem can be solved correctly with `UPDATE IGNORE`.

Comment: Yeah @KeluThatsall, update ignore is great, im avoiding it since he said 'I want to manupulate that row... and do some other stuff', and thats why i was trying to do some with on duplicate key